# Azure Database for Postgres Restore to point in time not working

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-postgresql

I have an Azure Database for Postgres instance that I wanted to roll back a few hours to grab some rows that I'd deleted. Using [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/howto-restore-server-portal) I tried to roll back one hour, a few hours, and a few days, but in all cases I'm seeing that the new database that's created from the Restore event has data in it that's newer than the selected point in time.

Is there some special step that I need to take to make this work as expected?

In case it helps, the Restore screen says that it has 35 days of backups.

**UPDATE (a few hours later):** This seems worse (or at least more confusing) than I originally thought.

I have `database-x`. I wanted to go back in time so I created a Restore for a point of time in the past and called this instance `database-x-restore--2021-09-25t09-00-00z`.

Looking at `database-x-restore--2021-09-25t09-00-00z` I see data more recent than the Restore point in time. (That's the original reason I filed this issue.)

But now, as I continue to work with `database-x` by adding new rows, I'm seeing `database-x-restore--2021-09-25t09-00-00z` also has those rows! but I have *nothing* connected to or interacting with this temporary database instance.

The original instance is a "Basic, 1 vCore(s), 10 GB" configuration, in case that matters.